# Install apache airflow in python 3.7.3

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, airflow

I have python2.7 and 3.7 both installed on my Mac machine. I have set python3 default in .bash_profile file using

```
alias python=python3
alias pip=pip3
```

when i hit the below command

```
pip install apache-airflow
```

it says

```
Requirement already satisfied: apache-airflow in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages (1.10.3)
```

But when i hit the command "airflow version", it says command not found.

So how to install apache airflow for python3

Comment: Have you tried to use virtual environments?

Answer (score 0):

You might need setup adjust the path environment variable accordingly.

My way to solve such environment case is to run applications in docker containers as micro service.